# Creating Call Logs with Recordings via Salesforce REST API

Tags: rest-api, salesforce1-app

I am successfully using the Salesforce REST API for various functionalities. However, I have a specific requirement regarding call logs and recordings. Is it possible to create a call log with an associated call recording through the API? The goal is to enable users to listen to recordings directly on the Lead Activity page. I've attached a reference screenshot for clarity. Any insights or guidance on achieving this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]